# How to have a multitouch application with multiple monitors?

Tags: wpf, touch, monitor, multi-touch, touchscreen

My app is multitouch and works fine on a single monitor, or with 2 monitors but 1 at a time.
But when I tried the multitouch on two monitors, the touch only works on the first that I touch, and the second monitor receive nothing... like if the first monitor get the focus of all touch device...

Is there a way to have 1 finger in each monitor at the same time?

I'm on Win7 64bits, .NET 4.0

2 dual touch monitors : NEC MultiSync LCD 2490WUXi²

Comment: Do they work multitouch in windows, outside the app? You are sure the touches don't transfer to the first window?

Comment: No it doesnt work in Windows, outside the app.

Comment: Multitouch works in Windows if I use something like ImageViewer, but only on 1 monitor, if I spread the imageviewer on both monitors, I cannot use 1 finger in each window...

Comment: Then that's your first priority. WPF only captures touches from Windows, not directly from the screens. Does the screens come with custom software? (Control Panel -> Tablet PC Settings -> Display -> Configure -> Setup to setup touchscreens to work with windows)

Comment: I found this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tabletandtouch/thread/9362757b-b0bd-4c2c-98e6-47bbaac0e496 It looks like it's not possible. (Just to confirm, you are able to use the second touchscreen, if you don't touch the first?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, there is only 2 possibilities to do multitouch on multiple monitors at the same time:

1) Use Mosaic (NVidia) or Eyefinity (ATI) to simulate that all monitors are only 1 monitor

2) Code the driver yourself to do exactly what you want